# Thailand visa extension denied because I applied too early

Tags: thailand, visa-extensions

I have landed in Bangkok two days ago and got a 45-day visa. Today, I went to the **IT Lak Si** center for short-term visa extensions in Bangkok to extend my visa for an extra 30 days.

I was denied and the 1,900 Baht I paid were returned to me, with an officer telling me that "it's too early" to extend the visa and that I would have to come back in one month (I paid around 300 Baht just to get there).

- Is this phenomenon unique to Bangkok or is it common in all provinces?
- Is there a clear definition in Thai law regarding this practice? For example, does Thai law declare that "only after 50% of the time of entering Thailand can a foreigner extend a visa" or anything like that?

Comment: See also: [Thailand Visa E-Extension (Electronic Visa Extension)](https://asq.in.th/thailand-e-extension-electronic-visa-extension)